# swift why this scroll view does not show subview?

Tags: swift, uiscrollview

testing with scrollviews programmatically, but cannot understand why this is not working. Logic wants I add a scrollview to my main view, then use it as reference for all subviews vince added to it.

```
let myView = UIView()
let myScroll = UIScrollView()

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myScroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        myScroll.backgroundColor = UIColor.cyan
        self.view.addSubview(myScroll)

        myScroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        myScroll.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        myScroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        myScroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true

        drawView(supVi: myScroll, addedVi: myView, color4View: .red, leading: 10, right: -10, top: 10, hei: -10)

    }

    func drawView(supVi: UIView, addedVi: UIView, color4View: UIColor, leading: CGFloat, right: CGFloat, top: CGFloat, hei: CGFloat) {

        supVi.addSubview(addedVi)
        addedVi.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addedVi.backgroundColor = color4View

        addedVi.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: supVi.leadingAnchor, constant: leading).isActive = true
        addedVi.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: supVi.topAnchor, constant: top).isActive = true
        addedVi.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: supVi.rightAnchor, constant: right).isActive = true
        addedVi.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: hei).isActive = true


    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two observations:

1. You’re setting the height constraint to -10. That doesn’t make any sense. I believe you intended to set the bottom constraint, not the height.
2. You’re setting the constraints of the scroll view’s subview, but that won’t set the size of the subview. These constraints will be used to set the `contentSize` of the scroll view (and your subview probably ends up with a `CGRect` of `.zero`).

   If you click on [image], the “Debug View Hierarchy” button, and navigate over to the runtime issues, you’ll see an “ambiguous content size” warning.

   [image]

   You need to add constraints that dictate the size of the subview. Consider:

   ```
   let myView = UIView()
   let myScroll = UIScrollView()

   override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       myScroll.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       myScroll.backgroundColor = .cyan
       view.addSubview(myScroll)

       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           myScroll.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
           myScroll.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -10),
           myScroll.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 10),
           myScroll.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
       ])

       addView(myView, to: myScroll, color: .red, leading: 10, trailing: -10, top: 10, bottom: -10)
   }

   func addView(_ addedView: UIView, to superview: UIView, color: UIColor, leading: CGFloat, trailing: CGFloat, top: CGFloat, bottom: CGFloat) {

       superview.addSubview(addedView)
       addedView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
       addedView.backgroundColor = color

       // these dictate the `contentSize` of the scroll view relative to the subview

       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           addedView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.leadingAnchor, constant: leading),
           addedView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.topAnchor, constant: top),
           addedView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.trailingAnchor, constant: trailing),
           addedView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: superview.bottomAnchor, constant: bottom)
       ])

       // these define the size of the `addedView`

       NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
           addedView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, multiplier: 0.5),
           addedView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, multiplier: 2.0)
       ])
   }
   ```

   In those last two constraints in the `addView` method, I’m deliberately setting the width of the `addedView` to be half the superview and its height to be twice of those of its superview, so you can see how

   - it scrolls;
   - the `contentSize` of the scroll view is set for you automatically through the magic of constraints you defined between the `addedView` and the scroll view; and
   - that the height of the subview is actually dictated by these two new constraints that I added to your original code snippet.

   Now, of course, I know you didn’t want it to be half as wide and twice as tall as the main view, and I only suggest you try that so you can get how it works. You can now just add the `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor` to be relative to the main view and you’ll get the desired effect.

   By the way, do not get rid of the constraints between the scroll view and its subview, because you need those, too. But add these additional constraints shown at the end of my snippet above.
3. Unrelated, I notice you’re setting the “leading” and “right” anchors. If you happened to be working with a RTL language, the “leading” anchor and the “right” anchor are the same thing, and you’d never be setting the “trailing” or “left” anchor.

   You really want to set the “leading” anchor and the *“trailing”* anchor, not the *“right”* anchor. Always use “leading” with “trailing” (or “left” with “right” if you don’t want to support RTL languages for some reason).

Comment: nice lesson @Rob, I'll try all your advices immediately